# Get a div id that has previously been randomly generated 

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to get a specific div id that is generated randomly. How can I catch the random div id to use with another function if I don't know the code that generates the random id? Thanks a lot!

HTML:

```
<html> 
<head> ... </head> 
<body> 
<div id="mybarxxxxx" style="height: 23px; ">... </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: eum. you might try catching it randomly? (we'll need a bit more info in order to answer your question)

Comment: You will get a more meaningful answer if you show the actual HTML and element you're trying to find.  Otherwise, only general advise can be offered.

Comment: well, if i want to hide the first div tag that i don't have the ID how i can combine this one:
`var header = document.getElementById("header");
var firstDivElement = header.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];` 
with this code: 
`document.getElementById('div_id').style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 4):

To get the DOM element for a particular div, you have to know something about it that uniquely identifies its location in the DOM.  That can be an ID, a class name that's unique, a position in the hierarchy under other known elements (such as the third div under #header), attributes that are unique, content, etc...

For example, if it was the first div under an element with id=header, then you could use 
this type of code:

```
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var firstDivElement = header.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
```

Or, if it was the third div in the document, you could get it this way:

```
var thirdDivElement = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[2];
```

We could advise more specifically if you show the actual HTML that you're looking in and tell us which element you're trying to get.

If you want to hide the very first div in the document, you can use this:

```
document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.display = "none";
```

If you want to hide the first div in the document who's id starts with "mybar" and you're limited to plain javascript, you can use this:

```
function hideFirstMyBarDiv() {
    var divs = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (divs[i].id.indexOf("mybar") == 0) {
            divs[i].style.display = "none";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

All of these code examples must be executed after the document has been loaded.  You can do that my placing your code in `<script>` tags at the end of the `<body>` (after all your HTML) or by listening for an event that signifies the document is loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But i am not a experimented guy trying to programming: Sorry. well, if i want to hide the first div tag that i don't have the ID how i can combine your code with this code: `document.getElementById('div_id').style.display = 'none';`

Comment: Show us your HTML.  We can't help with any more detail without seeing the HTML.

Comment: I have this div tag:
`<div id="random_div_id" style="height: 23px; ">... </div>`
and i want to hide this div tag with:
`document.getElementById('div_id').style.display = 'none';`
but i don't know the random div id for each refresh

Comment: @ManuelAndrésVélez - please read the answer I wrote again.  You can't find a div without knowing anything about it.  When you post all the relevant HTML of the document with this div in it, we can help you further.  Please read what we write.  Also, if/when you post the HTML, post it in your original question (use the Edit link), not in a comment.

Comment: I know, i don't know how to explain my situation...
HTML:
`<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body> <div id="mybarxxxxx" style="height: 23px; ">... </div> </body>` where the random string is the _xxxxx_ in the div id (the constant _mybar_ always is the same.) ok, in this order, i want to hide this div tag (is the first under _<body>_ Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like he's looking for `document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="div_id"]')` (or equivalent cross-browser code). I'm too tired to write an answer myself..

Comment: @ManuelAndrésVélez - I added two code examples to my answer above that shows you how to hide the first div in the body.

Comment: thanks a lot dude, i can edit this script to make it works! :D